# What while loop condition will I use to detect the input all lowercase?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, lowercase

What while loop condition will I use to detect the input all lowercase?

```
FirstName = input("Enter your First Name: ")
LastName = input("Enter your Last Name: ")

while FirstName.lower() and LastName.lower():
    print("Your First and Last Name should be typed in a lowercase letter")
    FirstName = input("Enter your First Name: ")
    LastName = input("Enter your Last Name: ")

print("Welcome")
```

Thank you for your help! Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: It actually the reverse of your condition that you need: `while first_name != first_name.lower() or last_name != last_name.lower():` May I offer you the advice of taking a look at the python PEP guides, especially 8 (styling guide)? It's best that you try to learn common practices right away (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps me to start out being very explicit in code about my intentions.  Your intention is to keep looping until the user enters all lower case letters for their first and last names, so `while not all_lower_case_entered` keep looping.  Inside your loop, your intention is to collect the user data and check to see if `full_name.islower()`.  If not, then print your error message, if so, set `all_lower_case_entered` to True.

Example:

```
all_lower_case_entered = False

while not all_lower_case_entered:
    first_name = input("Enter your first Name: ")
    last_name = input("Enter your last Name: ")
    
    full_name = first_name + last_name

    if not full_name.islower():
        print("Your first and last names should be typed in all lowercase letters.")
    else:
        all_lower_case_entered = True

print("Welcome")
```